# Google map dont show when the message contains " I'm "

Tags: google-maps, twitter

I'm working on mashup project on twitter with Google map
but when tweet message contain word " I'm " , the google map will not appear on the page
Is there any idea about that , Thanks

Comment: Probably the apostrophe ' causes problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are having trouble with escaping character. Try to replace I'm to I\'m .